# Is there evidence to suggest that sleeping requires more energy than watching TV?

Tags: neuroscience, metabolism, energy

I have [heard](http://www.news.dm/did-you-know-you-burn-more-calories-sleeping-than-you-do-watching-television/) the [claim](http://www.b-image-fit.com/did-you-know/sleeping-vs-watching-television/):

> sleeping requires [more energy than watching TV](http://pcmlifestyle.com/2015/09/sleeping-burns-more-calories-than-watching-tv/).

I have heard the counter-claim - [watching TV requires large amounts of energy](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/20034/14841).

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest that sleeping requires more energy than watching TV?**

Comment: This sounds like a better fit for skeptics.SE.

Comment: It fits with biology, too.

Comment: So your sources are 3 "news" websites that don't share sources and a parenting SE post?

Comment: It sounds like you have a better one. Please enlighten us.

Comment: So you have this question after reading a couple of "news" and lifestyle sites and a parenting site, which btw do not point to any external source? I think that before worrying about who would win between an elf and a troll I should check if those thing exist. I'm not sure they do, but the links you provided aren't it.

Comment: No, I'm saying this exists in the Zeitgeist. In common conversation. It is something that people talk about. These were the sites that came up when I searched for a truth that is commonly known.

Comment: I never wrote anything about calories in my answer over at Parenting SE. I simply started that the *brain* is active while the *body* may be relaxed when kids are sitting in front of a TV. I don’t think that it’s a suitable example for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Harvard Health Publishing](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diet-and-weight-loss/calories-burned-in-30-minutes-of-leisure-and-routine-activities). The weights are in pounds, and the energy is shown in calories. These values are for over a 30 minute period.

[image: Table]

This suggests that the claim is false; watching TV uses more energy than sleeping does.

Comment: Data is in pounds? Really? Pounds of what? Pounds sterling?

Comment: Pounds are a valid measurement of mass, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(mass). If you want me too, I can use kilograms, however for simplicity the data was in pounds and the conversion to kilograms gives decimal places, the removal of which reduces accuracy.

Comment: But that, I imagine, refers to the figures in bold. One could ask "mass of what?"  But as the question is about energy, I assume the non-bold figures are energy, which does not have units of mass.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realise that. Fixing that up now, and I'll fix the table up when I get on a PC